# Search Pattern Using Windows PERL

Tags: perl

My AIM is to search for a particular word or full statement and paste those words in another text file. For example you can take a log file and i need to find an exception for the particular date time and paste those in another text file example result.txt. Below are the following script. Please help me in this regard

```
chomp(@ARGV)

if(@ARGV!=2) {
    print "Please Pass two parameters";
    print "Usage: $ <File_name><pattern\n>";
}

$File_name     = $ARGV[0];
$res_File_name = $Filename . "\.res";
$Pattern       = $ARGV[1];

open(FD,"<File_name>")      or die("File $File_name could not be opened ");
open(WFD,"<res_File_name>") or die("File $res_File_name could not be opened ");

while(<FD>) {
    print WFD $-if(/$Pattern);
}

close(FD);
close(WFD);
```

This is a log text file

```
log.txt

2015-1-11 11:21:00 [Exception or Error] System.IO exception. I need to find those exceptions and paste that in result.txt. Not that only  i have a document say i have some paragraph ex: Hello World, i need to find that hello world and paste that in text file.
```

For this  i have passed two parameters here `if (@ARGV != 2)`, i need to print a message.

Second I need to pass those two parameters

`ARGV[0]`,`ARGV[1]`
`File_name` and `res_file_name` , i am getting scalar values from my original file and passing it to next res file.

O/p: `2015-01-10 or any other argument you pass that will be displayed`

Comment: Can you provide with the input and expected output which will try to simplify your problem and also get the best possible solutions. You can edit in your question by providing block of input and expected o/p

Comment: So the filename that you are passing as first parameter $ARGV[0] to the program is log.txt . So log.txt itself have Exceptions and also patterns that you sent as second parameter $ARGV[1] to the program ?

Comment: @Praveen Yes, note that the text file is not corrupted insted the logs written inside got some exception error

Comment: @Does the output for Exceptions and Pattern should go into $Filename.res or into two different output files ?

Comment: No output should go through single file res.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hari_cheerful: You can try the below perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(@ARGV);

if(@ARGV!=2)
{
    print "Please Pass two parameters\n". "Usage: <Filename><pattern>\n";
    exit;
}

my $Filename     = $ARGV[0];
my ($file,$ext) = $Filename =~ /(.*)(\..*?)/;
my $res_File_name = "$file" . "\.res";
my $Pattern       = $ARGV[1];

open(my $ip,'<', $Filename)      or die("File $Filename could not be opened ");
open(my $op,'>', $res_File_name) or die("File $res_File_name could not be opened ");

while(<$ip>) {
    if($_ =~ /$Pattern/is)
      {
         print $op $Pattern . "\n";
        }
     elsif($_ =~ /\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\s*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*\[Exception\s*.*?/is)
      {
         print $op $_ . "\n";
        }   

}
close($ip);
close($op);
```

Comment: Your code is working but i am unable to pass parameter

Comment: Usage: perl filename.pl log.txt "Hello" . Did u try the same ?

Comment: print "Please Pass two parameters\n". "Usage: <perl Search_Pattern1.pl><Hello>\n"; Please check

Comment: How do you run the program  ? Whether u run on command prompt or unix shell ?

Comment: perl followed by filename.pl followed by log.txt(First parameter) followed by Pattern(ex:"Hello") . So it will be in this format :  perl filename.pl log.txt "Hello"

Comment: The code works fine but it cut all the file from one text file and paste it in another text file. But i don't want the original file to be altered instead i need only copy say for ex 2015-1-11 11:21:00 [Exception or Error] System.IO exception that should only be copied and paste in result text file

Comment: No it will not cut or modify the original file . If the input is log.txt then the output is log.res which contains Exceptions and Pattern values but log.txt remains the same. Can you let me know the detail explanation of output that you got from running the program ? Edit the question and place o/p in it